# snmp and platform specific information

Tags: linux, snmp

I need to come with a strategy to use gather information about the health of my linux platform, hardware health such as high CPU temperature and may be disk space usage, etc... I know my examples are not very good ones.

Essentially, I have an SNMP agent running on Linux and I need it to provide platform specific health and state information. Are there any Linux packages that do this, what MIBs to use, Dell Open Manager functionality???

Any thoughts and comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.org/)

p.s. You should also remove the java tag from this question, and consider posting it on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) rather than on stackoverflow.